# switch to ear piece of WKWebview WebRTC call possible?

Tags: swift

i am using a `WKWebview`(webrtc) for audio call
initially the call is connected to audio output - speaker
but once i change the outport to ear piece - no sound

i am switching to ear piece once the call gets connected(it is received in handler).
once i received the status, using the following method, i changed to ear piece

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.none)
             
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

but once i call this method, audio becomes mute.
Anyhelp would be appreciable?